# Mouse Click with print dialog box does not working

Tags: vb6

I am using Active Reports  with VB6. When I try to print it, mouse click does not work with print diolog box. Although Alt + P with keyboard works well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work" ?